# Are there spaces "smaller" than $c_0$ whose dual is $\ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

It is well known that both the sequence spaces $c$ and $c_0$ have duals which are isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1$. Now, $c_0$ is a subspace of $c$. My question - is there an even smaller subspace of $c$ whose dual is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^1$? More generally, is there a characterization of preduals of $\ell^1$? References are most welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has an answer but it is extremely interesting (I've only read the first page or so for now): http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4325.pdf . $\ell^1$ does not have a unique predual which is really quite surprising to me.

Comment: Your question is not well posed because you have not given a rigorous definition of smaller. Indeed as sets $c_0$ is smaller that $c$, but in fact $c_0$ is *isomorphic* to $c$ as Banach spaces.

Comment: @noidentity yes. it's not well-posed, since I didn't define what exactly I mean by smaller. I assume that smaller means a strictly smaller subspace, but then realized that it could be given different meanings, so I just left it within quotes.

Comment: @CameronWilliams yeah. That seems an interesting read, and $\ell^1$ is indeed pathological in this sense.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Preduals of $\ell_1$ are very interesting creatures. The question is slightly ill-posed but let me comment on that anyway.

We have quite a lot of *isometric* preduals of $\ell_1$. Indeed, for any countably infinite ordinal number $\alpha$ (endowed with the [order topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology)) we have $C_0(\alpha)^* \cong \ell_1$. This essentially follows from the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) as every measure on such a space has to be [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29).

Note that $c_0 = C_0(\omega)$ and $c=C(\omega+1)$ are isomorphic. Actually for each $\alpha\in [\omega, \omega^\omega)$ we have $C_0(\alpha) \cong c_0$. However, there exist $\aleph_1$ many countable ordinals which give pair-wise non-isomorphic Banach spaces. To be more precise, if $\alpha, \beta$ are countable ordinals then $C(\omega^{\omega^\alpha}+1)$ and $C(\omega^{\omega^\beta}+1)$ are isomorphic if and only if $\alpha = \beta$.

Historically, the first example different from the above-mentioned ones was due to Y. Benyamini and J. Lindenstrauss:

> Y. Benyamini and J. Lindenstrauss. [A predual of $\ell_1$ which is not isomorphic to a $C(K)$ space](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02762798), *Israel J. Math.* **13** (1972), 246–254.

Johnson and Zippin proved that every isometric predual is a quotient of $C(\Delta)$, where $\Delta$ is the Cantor set.

> W.B. Johnson and M. Zippin, [Every separable predual of an $L_1$-space is a quotient of $C(\Delta)$](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02757870#page-1), *Israel J. Math.* **16** (1973), 198–202.

This result combined with an old result of Pełczyński

> A. Pełczyński, Banach spaces on which every unconditionally converging operator is weakly compact, *Bull. Acad. Pol. Sci. Ser. Math. Astr. Phys.* **10** (1962), 265–270.

asserting that an operator $T\colon C(K)\to X$ is weakly compact if and only if it is not bounded below on any isomorphic copy of $c_0$ yields the following corollary:

*Corollary*. Each isometric predual of $\ell_1$ contains a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$.

In some sense this answers OP's question.

One may wonder whether the Cantor set in the statement of the Johnson–Zippin theorem may be replaced by a countable compact Hausdorff space. This is not the case as shown by D. Alspach:

> D. E. Alspach, [A $\ell_1$-predual which is not isometric to a quotient of $C(\alpha)$](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9204215), *Contemp. Math.* **144**, Amer. Math. Soc., (1993), 9–14.

On the other hand, Gasparis constructed some new preduals of $\ell_1$ which are quotients of $C(\alpha)$:

> I. Gasparis, [A class of $\ell_1$-preduals which are isomorphic to quotients of $C(\omega^\omega)$](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm133/sm13323.pdf), *Studia Math.* **133** (2) (1999), 131–143.

Since there is no characterisation of complemented subspaces of $C(K)$-spaces, this result is also noteworthy:

> I. Gasparis, [A new isomorphic $\ell_1$ predual not isomorphic to a complemented subspace of a $C(K)$ space](http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/45/4/789.full.pdf+html), *Bull. London Math. Soc.* **45** (2013), 789–799.

If you are interested in spaces whose dual space is only *isomorphic* to $\ell_1$ then the situation is even more exciting. J. Bourgain and F. Delbaen constructed isomorphic preduals without subspaces isomorphic to $c_0$:

> J. Bourgain and F. Delbaen, [A class of special $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-spaces](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02414188), *Acta Math.* **145** (1980), 155–176.

A recent variation of the BD construction is the famous Argyros–Haydon space which is an isomorphic $\ell_1$-predual with the property that each operator on this space is of the form $cI + K$, where $c$ is a scalar and $K$ is a compact operator.

> S.A. Argyros and R.G. Haydon, [A Hereditarily Indecomposable $\mathscr{L}_\infty$-space that solves the scalar-plus-compact problem](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11511-011-0058-y#page-1), *Acta Math.* **206** (2011), no. 1, 1–54.

Even more recently, Spiros A. Argyros, Ioannis Gasparis and Pavlos Motakis constructed a $c_0$-asymptotic $\ell_1$-predual without copies of $c_0$:

> S.A. Argyros, I. Gasparis and P. Motakis, [On the structure of separable $\mathcal{L}_\infty$-spaces](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/pdf/1504.08223v1.pdf), *Mathematika* **62** (2016), no. 3, 685–700.

A nice overview of the BD-spaces (and some new variants of the Argyros–Haydon space) can be found in Matt Tarbard's PhD thesis:

> M. Tarbard, [Operators on Banach Spaces of Bourgain–Delbaen Type](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7469v1.pdf), PhD Thesis, University of Oxford, 2012.

I would also recommend the following paper by M. Daws, R. Haydon, Th. Schlumprecht and S. White

> M. Daws, R. Haydon, Th. Schlumprecht, and S. White, [Shift invariant preduals of $\ell_1(\mathbb{Z})$](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11856-012-0040-1#page-1), *Israel Journal of Mathematics*, **192** (2012), 541–585.

which explains these subtleties very well.

Laustsen and myself have exhibited a version of the Argyros–Haydon space whose algebra of bounded operators has certain peculiar properties:

> T. Kania and N.J. Laustsen, [Ideal structure of the algebra of bounded operators acting on a Banach space](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01213), *Indiana University Mathematics Journal* **66** (2017), 1019–1043.

Let me finish with an open problem (I think) which I like very much:

*Problem*. We can easily construct $\aleph_1$ many isometric preduals of $\ell_1$. Can we construct in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ continuum many isometric preduals of $\ell_1$?

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. That helps a lot. I guess I'll have to go a bit deeper in to measure theory.