# If equality of dual space of a Banach spaces implys the equality of pre-duals?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $ X_1$ and $X_2$ are two Banach Spaces such that $X_1\subset X_2$, i.e., the element belongs to $X_1$ belongs to $X_2$. No assumption on norms. Then I would expect that the dual space of them have the relation such that 
$$
X_2^\ast\subset X_1^\ast
$$
Now, if I know $X_1^\ast = X_2^\ast$, i.e., they share the same element. Then, do I have $X_1=X_2$ as well?

Comment: [Related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655718/why-is-this-inclusion-of-dual-of-banach-spaces-wrong) You generally have an inclusion $X_2^\ast \subset X_1^\ast$, or rather a canonical injection, only if the inclusion $X_1 \hookrightarrow X_2$ is continuous with dense image.

Comment: It might help to contemplate a case where $X\neq X^{**}$.

Comment: See this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966208/are-there-spaces-smaller-than-c-0-whose-dual-is-ell1/967079#967079